# JQuery dialog triggered through button is not shown

Tags: button, jquery-ui-dialog

I am struggling to open a `<div>` using a button in Jquery.
You can see my page (which is not working) [here](http://daado.altervista.org/calendario_corsi_certificazioni_2020.php).

Below is the code of my page.
Possibly I am not calling the dialog correctly, or it is somehow conflicting with the fullCalendar plugin I am using.

The dialog contains what I need, but it is not shown.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="img/clip.ico" />
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kube.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stile.css" />
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src='js/fullcalendar/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='js/fullcalendar/moment.min.js'></script>
      <script src='js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
      <script src='js/fullcalendar/it.js'></script>


     </head>
     <body>
    
    <button id="apricorsocae">lezioni corso CAE</button>
    
<div id="corsocae" title="lezioni corso CAE" style="display: none;"></div>

    <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#corsocae" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
          },
          hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
          }
        });
     
        $( "#apricorsocae" ).on( "click", function() {
          $( "#corsocae" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
      } );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the conflicting part:

```
<script src='js/fullcalendar/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

I've removed it and it seems to work fine.